# How does liquibase handle autoincremented PK's when generating changelogs from an existing table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am currently working on generating liquibase changelogs from an existing table in mySql. I have the id for a row set as it's PK and have it set to autoincrement.  Due to tests/different attempts to insert data into the table, the id's do not start at 1.

So my question is this, when generating changelogs from an existing table, does liquibase define the primary key for the child table based on the PK of the parent table (the table the liquibase was generated from)? Or when running the changelog on another database, will the primary key's for the new table start at 1 and autoincrement, regardless of the PK from the parent table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, auto_increment is handled by the database, not Liquibase.  So the new database's rows will start from 1.